# Awk multiple search terms with a variable and negation

Tags: bash, variables, awk, negate

I have a little test file containing:

```
awk this   
and not awk this  
but awk this  
so do awk this
```

And I've tried the following awk commands, in bash, but each produces no output:

```
f=awk; awk '/$f/ && !/not/' test.txt
f=awk; awk '/\$f/ && !/not/' test.txt
f=awk; awk '/"$f"/ && !/not/' test.txt
f=awk; awk -v f="$f" '/f/ && !/not/' gtest.txt
```

Using double quotes `"` produces "event not found" error in the shell due to the `!`.

How can I search on a variable and negate another string in the same command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `awk` like this:

```
f='awk'

awk -v f="$f" -v n='not' '$0 ~ f && $0 !~ n' file
awk this
but awk this
so do awk this
```

Or if you don't want to pass `n='not'` to `awk`:

```
awk -v f="$f" '$0 ~ f && $0 !~ /not/' file

awk this
but awk this
so do awk this
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

awk points to gawk for me and the following worked just fine:

```
awk -vf=awk '$0 ~ f && !/not/' file
```

Comment: There is nothing Gawk-specific here.  This appears to be a tweaked-down restatement of Anubhava's existing answer.